# systemd.network(5) get a value from file, or environment?

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd

I know that `*.service` units support `Environment=key=val` and `EnvironmentFile=fname` entries, but it appears that `*.network` files don't.

Is there any other way of getting, the value of an `Address` specifically, in from a different file or environment variable?

e.g. the result would be like:

```
# /etc/some/conf
192.0.2.3
```

```
# some.network
[Match]
Name=some

[Network]
# (! invalid !) example of desired effect
Address=$(cat /etc/some/conf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Systemd-networkd does not support loading data from external files (at least until February 2020 with systemd 244), so the best thing you can do is to write a `.service` file that syncs the key either way, and add `RequiredBy=systemd-networkd.service` and `Before=systemd-networkd.service` to make sure it does the job at the right time.

Comment: That's a neat solution that didn't occur to me, thanks. I can't find mention of something relevant in the 244 section of the NEWS file though - https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS - or did you mean 'as of up to 244 this isn't possible' rather than 'this is possible in 244'?

Comment: @OJFord "As of up to 244 this isn't possible" (245 isn't released yet, can't say for sure).

Answer (score 0):

From [systemd.network man](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html):

> The `.network` files are read from the files located in the system
>   network directories `/usr/lib/systemd/network` and
>   `/usr/local/lib/systemd/network`, the volatile runtime network directory
>   `/run/systemd/network` and the local administration network directory
>   `/etc/systemd/network`. All configuration files are collectively sorted
>   and processed in lexical order, regardless of the directories in which
>   they live. However, files with identical filenames replace each other.
>   Files in `/etc` have the highest priority, files in `/run` take precedence
>   over files with the same name under `/usr`. This can be used to override
>   a system-supplied configuration file with a local file if needed. As a
>   special case, an empty file (file size 0) or symlink with the same
>   name pointing to `/dev/null` disables the configuration file entirely
>   (it is "masked").

[...]

> An "`[Address]`" section accepts the following keys. Specify several
>   "`[Address]`" sections to configure several addresses.

Comment: Sorry, I think I might not have been clear: I know I can put several `.network` files in multiple locations, but I want just one, that loads its address from either a file that contains _only_ an IP address (no knowledge that it's going into a systemd file), or an env var. I've edited OP to make that clearer.

Comment: what about the `Address` section I've mentioned? according to man, you can specify many IP addresses there..

Comment: @OJFord , an example of such configuration here: https://superuser.com/a/775900/1049376

Comment: I'm not looking to specify many, just to specify one that's defined elsewhere.

Comment: as far as I'm aware, you cannot really do that.